# How to convert pixel to fr in css grid?

Tags: css, grid

I have a div container with a total width of 1000px and I decided to separate 5 columns using a CSS grid.
grid template columns : 100px 100px 100px 600px 100px;
how to convert this pixel to fr ?
grid template columns : ?fr ?fr ?fr ?fr ?fr;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `1fr 1fr 1fr 600px 1fr` which will make 4th one off 600px and rest will adjust according to remaining space

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate more on this? You haven't specified gap you want or not.
what can you do for now

```
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 6fr 1fr;
```

Also, let's say if you want a gap of 10px between the columns, then the same could be acheived by:

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 6fr 1fr;
grid-column-gap: 10px;
```